# Aggregate assignment of a variable and if statement

Tags: arrays, bash

I have some variables to check in my script and to prefix with "0" if there is only one character in it.

This is my code :

```
count_dev_nn=`echo "${#dev_nn[@]}"`
if [ ${#count_dev_nn} -eq 1 ]; then
        count_dev_nn="0"${count_dev_nn}
fi
```

(called several times for any different count_*_nn variables)

Is there a way to do this on one line ? To avoid to repeat if statement for each var ?

Comment: The `echo` is unnecessary: `count_dev_nn=${#dev_nn[@]}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
printf -v count_dev_nn '%02d' "${#dev_nn[@]}"
```

Use `printf '%02d'` to pad a number to two digits, and `printf -v` to assign the result to another variable. No `if` statement required.

If you're going to print this out eventually you could even just get rid of the `-v count_dev_nn`.